# How to create an array dynamically in a specified manner

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have multiple values coming from a database, it increases as new record is added.

I'm making span like this:

```
<span style="display:none;" class="skills"  data-skill="php programing">350</span>

<span style="display:none;" class="skills"  data-skill="java programing">235</span>

<span style="display:none;" class="skills"  data-skill="python programing">289</span>
```

I want to construct an array in this fashion

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['jobs', 'Jobs Available'],
          ['php programing',     350],
          ['java programing',     235],
          ['python programing',  289]
        ]);
```

so that I can be able to construct a google piechart dynamically

right now I am doing something like this

```
arrayToDataTable = [];
arrayTemp = [];
$.each('.skills',function(i){
 var skill = $(this).data('skill');
 var number = $(this).text();
  arrayTemp.push(skill);
  arrayTemp.push(number);
  arrayToDataTable.push(arrayTemp);
});


**my question how can i make array in this fashion dynamically:**

     [
          ['jobs', 'Jobs Available'],
          ['php programing',     350],
          ['java programing',     235],
          ['python programing',  289]
       ]
```

please help me thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: Did you check what you are getting in `console`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
arrayToDataTable = [];

$.each('.skills',function(i){
 var skill = $(this).data('skill');
 var number = $(this).text();
  arrayToDataTable.push([skill, number]);
});

console.log(arrayToDataTable);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span style="display:none;" class="skills"  data-skill="php programing">350</span>

<span style="display:none;" class="skills"  data-skill="java programing">235</span>

<span style="display:none;" class="skills"  data-skill="python programing">289</span>
```

Have you tried:

```
arrayToDataTable.push([arrayTemp])
```

Comment: what is the use of arrayTemp ?

Comment: Nothing really. That's just vestigial from OP's code. I'll clean that out

Comment: what about `['jobs', 'Jobs Available']` where do you add it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the proper each syntax, right now your arrayTemp  is defined globally so you keep adding element to it

try the following:

```
arrayToDataTable = [['jobs', 'Jobs Available']];

$('.skills').each(function(){
 var arrayTemp = [];//local variable
 var skill = $(this).data('skill');
 var number = $(this).text();
  arrayTemp.push(skill);
  arrayTemp.push(number);
  arrayToDataTable.push(arrayTemp);
});
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/uqxm0kf3/

or:

```js
 arrayToDataTable = [['jobs', 'Jobs Available']];
        
        $('.skills').each(function(){
    
         var skill = $(this).data('skill');
         var number = $(this).text();
          arrayToDataTable.push([skill,number]);
        });
console.log(arrayToDataTable);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span style="display:none;" class="skills"  data-skill="php programing">350</span>

<span style="display:none;" class="skills"  data-skill="java programing">235</span>

<span style="display:none;" class="skills"  data-skill="python programing">289</span>
```